# PyQt - is it possible to run two applications?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

Two files. Each runs new window and works by itself. I need to run them both.
When I run `first.pyw`, only one (second) window is shown.

Is it possible two run them both?

first.pyw:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import second

class first(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('first')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
firstApp = first()
firstApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

second.pyw:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class second(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('second')

app2 = QApplication(sys.argv)
secondApp = second()
secondApp.show()
sys.exit(app2.exec_())
```

How can I run two applications that are in different modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only run a single application at a time, although your application can have multiple top-level windows. The [QCoreApplication docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qcoreapplication.html#details) say that:

> ...there should be exactly one QCoreApplication object.

This also holds true for QApplication as it derives from QCoreApplication. You can get access to that application through the [QCoreApplication.instance()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qcoreapplication.html#instance) method or the [qApp](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qapplication.html#qApp) macro in C++.

What do you expect to get out of having two different applications running? Instead, you could have each module provide a top-level window that then gets displayed by the application launcher.

Comment: On module have `read_file` function. If it catch error, it should rise new popup window. So, `.show()` should be in module itself.

Comment: But I got it, it is not possible, it is an answer.

Comment: Kalep, trolltech documentation links are intentional or hidden jokes? :)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is essentially right, but there are cases where you want to run multiple QApplications one after the other, e.g. :

- Unit tests
- A command-line tool that shouldn't require a running X server (hence no QApplication on startup), but can optionally show a window if the user's system supports it

I ended up using the `multiprocessing` module to start each `QApplication` in a separate process, so that each one is independent from the others.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
class MyApp(Process):

   def __init__(self):
       self.queue = Queue(1)
       super(MyApp, self).__init__()

   def run(self):
       app = QApplication([])
       ...
       self.queue.put(return_value)

app1 = MyApp()
app1.start()
app1.join()
print("App 1 returned: " + app1.queue.get())

app2 = MyApp()
app2.start()
app2.join()
print("App 2 returned: " + app1.queue.get())
```

Answer (score -1):

You import second. Hence it is interpreted before you even reach the definition of class first. As the last line of second.pyw is sys.exit, nothing behind it can be executed.

Comment: I make it just `app2.exec_()` and now first window runs after second. But not simultaneously.

Comment: Because `.exec_()` returns only when the applications that's run is shut down.

Comment: Create two threads. In one thread call app.exec_ (), in the other thread call app2.exec_ ()

Comment: So there is no way to do it. I'll try to connect them from one application.

Comment: Hyperboreus, yes there is a solution. But I will try to do it in one thread, so they can share with each other.

Comment: Just create one application and start both Widgets from it.